# How do I properly center this div on mobile and desktop

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position, responsive

```
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
    height: 100%;
    background: hsl(212, 45%, 89%);
    
}

.container {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin: 1.1em;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    body {
        height: 100vh;
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
    }
    .container {
        margin: auto;
        width: 45%;
    }
```

Mobile version just doesn't vertically center.
Desktop ver is centered but there's a scrollbar because of body: 100vh;

Editing the margin doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `min-height: 100vh` to vertically center the div. This way it will take the full height but won't make the page scrollable.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;  /*add this to remove the default body margin*/
}
body{
    /*height: 100%;*/ /*<---replace this with min-height: 100vh;*/
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background: hsl(212, 45%, 89%);   
}

.container {
    /*margin: auto;        don't need margin: auto;*/
    height: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    /*body {         <---don't need to specify this anymore
        height: 100vh;
        display: grid;
        place-items: center;
    }*/
    .container {
        width: 45%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container"><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex-box` to center anything, apply the following `CSS` to it.

To show it aligns the item to the center, I made a red box.

Now you can add more `CSS` to it.

```css
.hero{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh
}
.container{
  background : red;
  width: 100px;
  height :100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
        <div class="container"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Although it only fixed the desktop version. In mobile, there's still some space underneath the container...

Comment: Oh! I didn't see you also want to vertically center this, I have edited the code please check now.